# What is Perl doing with this argument to push in this case?

Tags: perl

I just saw some code in our code base (and it's OLD code, as in Perl 3 or Perl 4 days) that looks like this (I'm simplifying greatly):

```
 @array;
 push( array, $some_scalar );
```

Notice that the `array` in the `push()` doesn't have an `@`.  I would assume that the code behind push knows that the first argument is supposed to be array so grabs the array from the `array` typeglob.  Is that more or less it?  If Perl is able to do that without problem, why would you need to include the `@` at all?

Comment: Run this code with `use warnings` and see if that answers your question.

Comment: Turning warnings on for this old code would be an unmitigated disaster, but I get your point.

Comment: @Monirar: if you have to maintain this code, improving it to run with warnings enabled could proof very useful though.

Comment: Cool OP. I love learning about the weird deprecated cruft that permeates Perl 5. :)

Comment: @Leon - I would LOVE to get all of our Perl strict/warnings compliant, but we're talking about hundreds of thousands/millions of lines of code. Plus, the PHBes don't see strong value in doing such things.

Comment: Ouch! I pity you for having to maintain that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an old 'feature' of the parser. The @ isn't mandatory in a push if the variable is a package variable. This is considered by many as a bug that ought to be fixed though. You really shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to actually perform the push, though. With this: `perl -e 'my @array = (); push (array, "foo"); print "@array\n";'` I get no output. DId I do something dumb?

Comment: Maybe it does have something to do with typeglobs then. Jefromi's sample code above doesn't output anything, but if you remove the `my`, then it does.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It only seems to work for package variables.

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure the original array wasn't declared with my. I merely wrote that into the example as a force of habit.

Answer (score 4):

This is a dubious "feature" of perl, deprecated behaviour; it should be an error, but it works.

If you turn on the warnings of the compiler (*perl -W*, highly recommended), it warns:

```
Array @aa missing the @ in argument 1 of push() at xx.pl line 2.
```

Answer (score 2):

[Nicholas Clark explains](http://use.perl.org/~nicholas/journal/39741):

> That's Perl 1 syntax.